# How to write a trigger to fire a task to a public group whenever an article is created(as draft) in the 'Article management' tab.

Tags: trigger, knowledge

How to write a trigger to fire a task to a public group whenever an article is created(when they are in draft) in the 'Article management' tab. This is to send a task to the public group/team to read the article which is created and then the team has to publish it.  Workflow rules are not available for Article management/Knowledge articles. Thanks !

Comment: Workflow rules are available on Knowledge articles: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_setup_wflow_approvals.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a trigger because triggers are not available for articles, but you can create a workflow rule on the article type.  If you have an article type. called "FAQ", you should be able to create a workflow rule on the FAQ object.

**UPDATE:**

If the tasks are not available as actions for these objects, you can do the following:

Create a workflow rule on the article object.
Have an email alert to be sent to an [email service address](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com)
Create a handler for the email service and from that class, create the task through from apex.

Comment: Thanks.I tried for the article type. But there is no task alert workflow associated with it. Anyother workaround for assigning a task to a public group when an article is created?

Comment: @Sfdcas I have updated my answer.

Comment: I tried this . It creates a task but I want the task to be related to the particular knowledge article which fired the email alert workflow? how is that possible?

Comment: @sfdcas is not possible unless you go the apex way.